# Get url pattern in middleware's handle method in laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

In routes.php I have defined route as

```
Route::get('entities/{id}/queries','QueryController@fetch');
```

and the actual example url is (for example): http://localhost:8000/entities/5/queries

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null) {
   echo $request->path(); //returns entities/5/queries
   return $next($request);
}
```

Now I need to access that url pattern in middleware. 
i.e. **entities/{id}/queries**.
Is there any method that returns the url pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using the route inside your `$request` object.

Like this:

`$request->route()->uri();`

This will return `entities/{id}/queries` in your case.